# Regex - match everything after specific sign with enter

Tags: regex

Like in title it would be simple if text is only in one line but what if there are enters. So what would be the patter to obtain the output of below text, the specific sign is SI:

Input Text:

```
blfadsf32r4 32 325 32fasfsda fa  32
- 14x/111f/167s
fsafsa f ffew mf32k fsaf
SI - 13d/234f/1das
dsadsaf safsaf 32
fsda fsdaf32f
```

Output:

```
 - 13d/234f/1das
dsadsaf safsaf 32
fsda fsdaf32f
```

Thanks

Comment: any attempts?On what criteria the match should stop?

Answer (score 2):

You want a match that spans lines   [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/qM7uE7/2):

```
(?s)SI(.*$)
```

where

```
(?s) - matches everything as a single line
SI   - matches SI
(.*$) - matches and captures everything after that.
```

Comment: Volunteer work is good all in all, but not when you do it on SO. It is not a do-it-for-you site.